# CLUSTER not shrinking table size while running other transactions using Psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

We are running a python process which runs this stored procedure, which import files from a certain directory to the postgres database. These files are first get imported to a in-memory table and then to the disk table. The actual size of the in-memory table should never really grow beyond 30 MB. As this table is constantly updated, the size of the table grows (because of dead tuples). To keep things in check, we need to perform CLUSTER operation on the table. I am using psycopg2 module to run stored procedure adn CLUSTER the table, but if the import process is running the size of the table never goes down. But If I stop the import process and run CLUSTER then the size of the table goes down. Because of the performance reason, I should be able to run CLUSTER command without stopping the import procedure.

I tried manual commit, ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT but none of this has worked.
Below is the sample code of the process -

```
while True:
    -get the filenames in directory
    for filpath in  filenames:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='dbname' user='user' password='password'")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        # Calls a postgresql function that reads a file and imports it into 
        # a table via INSERT statements and DELETEs any records that have the 
        # same unique key as any of the records in the file.
        cursor.execute("SELECT import('%s', '%s');" % (filepath, str(db_timestamp))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        os.remove(get_media_path(fname))
```

With the similar conn object, I want to run CLUSTER command once an hour -

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='dbname' user='user' password='password'")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CLUSTER table_name")
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Also, I tried setting -

```
conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
```

Another piece of information - 
I have all this running inside django environment. I could not use django connection objects to do the task because - django could not  release connections with my threading code and soon the database stopped accepting connections.Does this mixed environment might have an effect on psycopg?

Few observations -

1. Running the CLUSTER command when import process is running - size doesn't go down
2. When I stop the import process and then run CLUSTER - size does go down
3. When I stop the import process and start import process back, and after that run CLUSTER command - size does go down

Any thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I found the culprit.

The problem was somehow the cluster or vacuum were not deleting the dead tuples, because some weird interaction was happening when we using pstcopg2 directly in django environment. After isolating the psycopg code and removing the django related code from import-process, everything worked fine. This solved the problem and now I can vacuum or cluster it without stopping the import-process.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

> When a table is being clustered, an
>   ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock is acquired on
>   it. This prevents any other database
>   operations (both reads and writes)
>   from operating on the table until the
>   CLUSTER is finished.

Are you sure you have to CLUSTER every hour? With a better fillfactor and autovacuum, your table won't grow that much and you won't have dead tuples in the table.

Comment: yeah I am fine with it preventing read and writes during the cluster operation time. But the problem is the size doesn't go down after the cluster runs. Also, autovaccum and vaccum full doesn't help either. the table size keeps growing.

Comment: When even VACUUM FULL doesn't shrink the table, you don't have that many dead tuples at all. But again, use a better fillfactor to give the database the chance to use HOT updates. This will help to avoid the need for extra space.

Comment: I appriciate you replying to this thread. But you understand the problem here. Its not that vacuum full or cluster doesn't shrink the table size. They do shrink the table size when I stop the import process and run either of them. But when I am running import process - which is continuously inserting and deleting (using stored procedure which is run by psycopg2) from the table - then if even if I run CLUSTER or VACCUM FULL it doesn't shrink the size.

Comment: And that's because CLUSTER and VACUUM FULL need a table lock, that they can't get because of other processes. Do you realy need to CLUSTER? As I said before, using a better fillfactor might change everything and you don't need CLUSTER at all or that often.